# How do I make this code works for Server and Client on different machines?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, client-server

Server

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
    int slen, recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;

    slen = sizeof(si_other);

    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //Bind
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    puts("Bind done");

    //keep listening for data
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for data...");
        fflush(stdout);

        //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
        memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);

        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //print details of the client/peer and the data received
        printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
        printf("Data: %s\n", buf);

        //now reply the client with the same data
        if (sendto(s, buf, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    /*string line;
    ifstream myfile("info.xml");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "unable to open file";
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Client

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"  //ip address of udp server
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, slen = sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char message[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;

    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //create socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("socket() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //setup address structure
    memset((char *)&si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);

    //start communication
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter message : ");
        //gets(message);
        fgets(message, BUFLEN, stdin);

        //send the message
        if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //receive a reply and print it
        //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
        memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);
        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        puts(buf);
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

It works if both the server and client code is running on the same machine. I want to know what I need to change if I want it to work for two different machines? Both machines are connected to the same WIFI, running Windows 10. I'm a noob when it comes to C++ and networking, please go easy on me thanks.

Comment: Don't ask questions which can only be understood by following links.

Comment: You'd rather let me post the code that is basically everything in the article that the link leads you too? OK then

Comment: @nomnom Questions are expected to be self contained here. Also ask about specific problems and provide a [MCVE]. Emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: @nomnom: Not quite. I am asking you to turn the information on that other page into a short, understandable question here. Chances are that the question is off-topic anyway, because SO is about specific problems which you encounter *after* you have written some code already.

Comment: The code is here now, I didn't post it because it is exactly the same as the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client code `#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"` means the server is on the localhost.

You can check what is your server IP(like using `ipconfig` from command prompt), and set the `SERVER` macro.

Note that you maybe need to do some configuration work, like open the port in firewalls.

first you should check connectivity between the two machines, you can do it usimg `ping` command with the target IP

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the two addresses. 192.168.0.11 and 13, I tried to ping from one to the other, but all packages lost. Do you know what I should do now?

Comment: I can ping now, and I'll try changing the SERVER.